# MySQL inner join horizontal columns

Tags: mysql

Can anybody help me on creating a MySQL query which would display result as shown below? There could be maximally 3 photos on each item (or there does not have to any photo at some items).

**Table ITEMS**

| id | item_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | computer |
| 2 | mobile |
| 3 | laptop |
| 4 | tablet |

**Table PHOTOS**

| id | item_id | photo_file |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | f01.jpg |
| 2 | 2 | f02.jpg |
| 3 | 4 | f03.jpg |
| 4 | 4 | f04.jpg |
| 5 | 4 | f05.jpg |
| 6 | 1 | f06.jpg |

**Standard query**

```
select item_name, photo_file from ITEMS a INNER JOIN PHOTOS b on a.id=b.item_id
```

result:

| item_name | photo_file |
| --- | --- |
| mobile | f01.jpg |
| mobile | f02.jpg |
| tablet | f03.jpg |
| tablet | f04.jpg |
| tablet | f05.jpg |
| computer | f06.jpg |

**REQUIRED RESULT**

| item_name | photo_file_1 | photo_file_2 | photo_file_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mobile | f01.jpg | f02.jpg | null(or empty) |
| tablet | f03.jpg | f04.jpg | f05.jpg |
| computer | f06.jpg | null(or empty) | null(or empty) |

Answer (score 1):

With MySql >= 8.0 you can do something like this:

First I get the row number for each photo (starting from one for each item), then I `GROUP BY` item_name and use `CASE` statement to pivot the result.

```
WITH sq AS (SELECT item_name, photo_file,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.id ASC) AS rn
            FROM ITEMS i 
            INNER JOIN PHOTOS p ON i.id = p.item_id)

SELECT item_name, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN photo_file END) AS photo_file_1,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN photo_file END) AS photo_file_2,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 3  THEN photo_file END) AS photo_file_3
FROM sq
GROUP BY item_name
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats exactly what I was not able to figure out.

Comment: You are welcome @LukášJežek!!!